# Notice Array to string conversion in

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Ran into an issue with simply querying and returning the suggestID value. 
I keep getting Array to string conversion, so i'm a bit lost. I'm

**Javascript**

```
 $('#autocomplete').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data);
    var dataID = data;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "get.php",
     data: $.param({itemID: dataID }),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
});
})
```

**Get PHP FILE**

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['itemID'])) {

$db = new DbConnect;
$conn = $db->connect();
$str = $_POST['itemID'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$str'");

$stmt->execute();
$result= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);   
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"Array to string conversion"_?

Comment: Note you are sending `ItemID` and looking for `itemID` in `$_POST`. Should also set `dataType` since you aren't adding content type header in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itemID` parameter is being treated as an array by PHP:

```
$str = $_POST['itemID'];
```

If you were to `var_dump` that you might see that `$str` is an array.

When the `data` passed to [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is an object and one of the property values is an array, [`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) will serialize it using the array bracket syntax, which PHP automatically treats as an array. For example:

```
$.param({key: [1, 2, 3]}); // "key[]=1&key[]=2&key[]=3"
```